# Stop kubernetes cluster on Autopilot mode

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a kubernetes cluster set up and I want to stop it so it doesn't generate additional costs, but keep my deployments and configurations saved so that it will work when I start it again. I tried disabling autoscaling and resizing the node pool, but I get the error `INVALID_ARGUMENT: Autopilot clusters do not support mutating node pools.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GKE (autopilot or not) you pay 2 things

- The control plane, fully managed by Google
- The workers: Node pools for GKE, the running pods on GKE Autopilot.

In both case, you can't stop the control plane, you don't manage it. The only solution is to delete the cluster.

In both case, you can scale your pods/node pools to 0 and therefore remove the worker cost.

---

That being said, in your case, you have no other solution than deleting your Autopilot control plane, and to save your configuration in config file (the yaml files). Next time you want to start your autopilot cluster, create a new one, load your config, and that's all.
For persistent data, you have to save them outside (on GCS for instance) and to reload them also. The boring part.

*Note: you have 1 cluster free per billing account*